# Struts 2 pass dynamic url from action to action

Tags: struts2

I need to pass some parameters from action A to action B, with the parameters in Action A. The Action B's url will have the Action A's parameters printed.Therefore the flow is:

Action A

```
param1 = param1Val;
param2 = param2Val;
param3 = true;
param4 = 0;
```

in Action B, the url is

```
ActionB?param1=param1Val&param2=param2Val&param3=true&param4=0;
```

I have tried something like [**this**](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.2/docs/redirect-action-result.html)

But it didn't work.

What can I do to make it start working?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very much clear but still if you want to pass some parameters from your first action to second action using `redirectAction`, all you have to create those parameters in your first action (Action A) and while configuring your second action (Action B) you need to tell S2 that you want to pass those parameters to action B.

```
 <action name="a" class="ClassA">
        <!-- Redirect to another namespace -->
        <result type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">B</param>
            <param name="param1">${param1}</param>
            <param name="param2">${param2}</param>
             // any other parameters
        </result>
    </action>
```

key concept here is the use of `${param1}` to pass dynamic parameters in configuration, this will look in to parameter named `param1` in the value stack and will be replaced by its value in run time.

Make sure you have those parameters which you want to pass to your action B in your action A with there getters and setters so the S2 can pick them at run time.

Not if you want to pass static parameters in your configuration, all you need to do like

```
<action name="a" class="ClassA">
            <!-- Redirect to another namespace -->
            <result type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">B</param>
                <param name="param1">param1</param>
                <param name="param2">param2</param>
                 // any other parameters
            </result>
        </action>
```

Not here parameters are being passed as `param1` and not `${param1}`

Comment: Thanks Umesh,

I tried that but it didn't really work...

Here's the complex part...

What I'm trying to do here is actually, the result of Action B is actually a link that is being clicked from Action A Therefore, in Action A, I have this href URL that is like this:

    ActionB?param1=param1Val&param2=param2Val&param3=true&param4=0;

But all these parameters: 
    **param1=param1Val&param2=param2Val&param3=true&param4=0;** 
are set from Action A before passing in to Action B.

So if I use the set methods in Action A, will I be able to get them in Action B?

Comment: no, these values will not be available in your Action B if you are using `redirectAction`, only way is either save them in session and retrieve them in your action B or pass them as query string to Action B and fetes values from query string in action B.